# How to create multiple entries in a ManyToManyField programatically

Tags: database, django, postgresql, django-models, many-to-many

A noob question, I'm afraid. I have a database with several classes, among them the class picture and page:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)

class Page(models.Model):
    page_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    pictures = models.ManyToManyField(Picture)
```

Creating new pictures entries in my database is straight forward:

```
newPic = Picture.objects.create(picture_uuid="SAMPLE-UUID")
newPic2 = Picture.objects.create(picture_uuid="SAMPLE2-UUID")
newPic3 = Picture.objects.create(picture_uuid="SAMPLE3-UUID")
```

etc.

However, I have no idea how to add these pictures to a certain page:

```
newPage = Page.objects.create(page_uuid="SAMPLE-PAGE-UUID", pictures= … )
```

What if I wanted to achieve this programatically, i.e. adding my three pictures to this newPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in the next statement:

```
newPage = Page.objects.create(page_uuid="SAMPLE-PAGE-UUID")
newPage.pictures.add(newPic, newPic2, newPic3)
```

[In the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)